# $n \equiv 7 \pmod{8}$, prove $\sigma(n) \equiv 0 \pmod{8}$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

> Let $\sigma(n)$ denote the sum of all divisors of $n$. If $n \equiv 7 \pmod{8}$, show that $\sigma(n) \equiv 0 \pmod{8}$.

If $n$ is prime, by definition, $\sigma(n)=n+1\equiv 0\pmod{8}$. But how to prove it is also true if n is a composite?

Comment: Not all know/can guess what a symbol is. Define $\;\sigma\;$ .

Comment: It's a number theoretic function for the sum of the positive (integer) divisors of $n$.

Comment: $sigma$ denote the sum of positive divisors of n

Comment: A broad hint: $\sigma(n)$ is a _multiplicative_ function, and therefore so is $\sigma(n)\bmod 8$ (why?).  If $n\equiv 7\pmod 8$, what are the possible factorizations of $n$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is interestingly related to a question I posed a few days ago. ([Classification of moduli where relatively prime numbers squared are 1](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1761564/classification-of-moduli-where-relatively-prime-numbers-squared-are-1))

$8$ is one of few numbers with the property that if $\gcd(x,8)=1$, then $x^2\equiv 1($mod$ 8)$. (See for yourself: $1^2\equiv 1, 3^2\equiv 1, 5^2\equiv 1, 7^2\equiv 1$.) For any such $x$ then, $-x^2\equiv -1$. If you can just show that all divisors of $n$ are relatively prime to $8$(where $n\equiv -1 ($mod$ 8)$), then for any divisor $x$ of $n$, $y\equiv -x$ (mod $8$) where $y$ is the complementary divisor of $x$ (that is, $y$ such that $xy=n$). Then when you evaluate the sum of divisors of $n$, you can pair the complementary divisors of $n$ and they will always sum to $0$ (mod $8$). (You should also note that no divisor is its own complementary divisor, which should be obvious.)

I should probably note here that I don't think this is the easiest answer, but I found it interesting, and once you get the idea, it's pretty fast.

Comment: This is a much better answer than the hint I had in comments - really nice!